# How do you prove that an IV estimator is (in general) inconsistent if the first stage regression does not include a constant?

Tags: instrumental-variables, consistency, 2sls

Given an equation
$$
Y = \alpha + \beta X + u
$$
where $X$ is an endogenous variable and $Z$ is a valid instrument for $X$.

Then suppose that
$$
X = \gamma + \pi Z + v
$$
is the true data generating process but
$
X = \pi Z + v
$
is estimated instead. I understand that the estimate $\hat{\pi}$ is then biased, but how would you then use this to prove that $\hat{\beta}$ is inconsistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substituting for $X$ in the equation of $Y$ we get

$$ Y = \left(\alpha + \beta\gamma \right) + \beta\pi Z + \left( \beta v + u \right)$$

If we estimate

$$ Y = \lambda + \theta Z + e $$

and $Z$ is a good instrument, $ \hat\theta \overset{p}{\to} \beta\pi $ and $ \hat\pi \overset{p}{\to} \pi $.

$$ \hat\beta_{IV} = \frac{\hat\theta}{\hat\pi} $$

By [Slutsky’s theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem) $\hat\beta_{IV} \overset{p}{\to} \frac{\beta\pi}{\pi} = \beta $ since both $\hat\theta$ and $\hat\pi$ are consistent estimators for $\beta\pi$ and $\pi$, respectively.

I’m not good at writing proofs, but from here it seems obvious why $\hat\beta_{IV}$ would be inconsistent if $\hat\pi$ is.